# Simultaneously existing a template function with std::enable_if and an ordinary template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, enable-if

I have a simple function:

```cpp
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
foo(T val) { }
```

I would like also to have another function with the same name:

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(T value) { }
```

I want to call the first function with arithmetic types and the second function for all other types. An idea I have is to change the second function into this:

```cpp
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
foo(T val) { }
```

but is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: why do you think it needs to be "better" ? Consider how your first `foo` looks like when `T` is arithmetic, and how it is different from your second `foo` (it isn't)

Comment: offtopic: `typename` in last example is obsolete. `typename` is needed for dependent types which are hidden here.

Comment: A better way is to use concepts.

Comment: @康桓瑋 please provide an example. AFAIK in this scenerio concepts will have same ambiguity which have to be resolved.

Comment: @MarekR: With concepts, you get overloading for free, as the more refined overload will be selected over the more generic overload. That being said, depending on the contents of the function, `if constexpr` would be the preferred choice.

Answer (score 2):

A better and more intuitive way is to use C++20 concepts.

```
#include <concepts>

template<class T>
  requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
void foo(T value) { }

template<class T>
void foo(T value) { }
```

When you call `foo(0)`, since the constraint of the first overload is satisfied, it will take precedence over the second unconstrainted overload.

When you call `foo("hello")`, since the constraint of the first overload is not satisfied, the compiler will select the second overload.

Answer (score 2):

Use `if constexpr`:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T value)
{
  if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>) {
    // ... one implementation
  } else {
    // ... another implementation
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by leverage overload resolution:

```cpp
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
foo(T val, int)
{
    std::cout << "arithmetic: " << (val + val) << '\n';
}

template<typename T>
void foo(const T& val, long)
{
    std::cout << "Def: " << val << '\n';
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& x)
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(x), 0);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sM1KbT8vE

now `int` overload is preferred, but if it fails because of SFINAE it jumps to `long` overload.

In simple case I prefer `!std::eneble_if_t` approach, but if you have more special cases overload resolution is more handy.